# Orderby with join laravel check empty result

Tags: php, laravel

I have this relation:

```
 public function romwords()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\RomWord', 'dwruId', 'dwruId')
    ->leftJoin('dwords_ro_black', 'dwords_ro_black.dwroId', '=', 'dwords_ro.dwroId')
    ->orderBy('isMd', 'desc');
}
```

Сolumn `isMd` on table `dwords_ro`. On table `dwords_ro_black` only columns `id`, `dwroId`

I need orderBy with column `isMd` only when leftJoin is empty (empty results).
How I can check this?

Comment: How do you want to sort rows that haven't got leftJoin? Sort them to the end?

Comment: @IndianCoding yea

Comment: type of isMd? And what it contains? Some example.

Comment: @IndianCoding type of isMd tinyInt can be `0`, or `1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function romwords()
{
    return $this
        ->hasMany('App\RomWord', 'dwruId', 'dwruId')
        ->leftJoin('dwords_ro_black', 'dwords_ro_black.dwroId', '=', 'dwords_ro.dwroId')
        ->orderByRaw('
            CASE
                WHEN dwords_ro_black.id IS NULL THEN 1
                WHEN dwords_ro.isRo = 1 AND dwords_ro.isMd = 1 THEN 1
                WHEN dwords_ro.isMd = 1 THEN 0
                WHEN dwords_ro.isRo = 1 THEN 2
            END
        ');
}
```

Comment: `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, dwords_ro.isMd DESC' at line 1` error :(

Comment: Working. But can we do, rows without leftJoin will be in the second position?

Comment: I have column isRo, isRo now is second, can we change isRo with  your solution? Must be isRo on the end.

Comment: I need sort with priority: isMd (on first, all records with isMd on first), with empty leftJoin (on second, all records without leftJoin, where it is empty), and isRo (on third, where all records with isRo)..

Comment: Now I get `isRo` firstly :(, leftJoin is second now, and isMd on third

Comment: Now I get with leftJoin firstly, and isMd on second and isRo on third ;((

Comment: Now I get `isRo` firstly, `isMd` second, and leftJoin on third :(

Comment: @Dumitru Can row have isRo and isMd at once?

Comment: Yea, can be isRo = 1 and isMd = 1, if isRo = 1 and isMd = 1 put please on second

Comment: Nope :( I get now isRo firstly .. .(

Comment: @Dumitru let's try)

Comment: Now isMd firstly, isRo second, but leftJoin on third :)

Comment: I don't believe. Last option) I think it is similar to previous.

Comment: Now I get same result :)

Comment: @Dumitru isRo can be on second if it doesn't have leftJoin or isMd = 1 too. You said: if isRo = 1 and isMd = 1 put please on second

Comment: Put on second only if isRo = 1 && isMd = 1, only in this cause